# How to use different versions of local Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, swift-package-manager

I would like to create a local Swift Package to share code between different projects. Creating and adding the package to a project was no problem. However, other with third party packages I have no control over what version of the package is being used.

When adding a third-pary package to my project I can specify which version and update rule (e.g. up to next major version) should be used. However, when adding a local package this option is missing:

[image]

Regarding the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/publishing-a-swift-package-with-xcode) versioning should be possible by putting the package under version control and tagging the commits with a version number. This what I did for `MyPackage`:

[image]

I have create an `Initial` commit and tagged is with `1.0.0`. A second commit is tagged `2.0.0` and a third commit does NOT have a version tag. Additionally there are some un-commited changes.

When adding the Package to my project I would expect to be able to select a branch or a version. When selecting the `main` branch I would expect to see code version `v3`. When selection version 2 I would expect to see version from commit `v2` with tag `2.0.0`.

Instead no branch / version selection is offered and the un-commit version 4 is added to the project.

**How can this be changed?**

Comment: You should not use a local package for this and for git you will need to use a git service that is accessible from any project where you need the package. Normally GitHub is used for this but you can probably set up your own git server if you want to.

Comment: Mmh, isn't GitHub just a remote repository I push my local changes to and from where I can pull commits? What is the difference to any git repository on my local machine? Currently the package uses "only" one git repo (in package root dir). Of course I can add any number of remote repos, either on my local machine or anywhere else. But what would be the difference? Beside my local machine I use a git server on my Synology NAS. However, it makes no difference if I add my local package from my Mac or from the NAS.

Comment: It should be fine as long as your other projects can access that repository. From the docs _”A package author can publish their Swift package to either public or private repositories. Xcode supports both private and publicly available packages.”_. Note the word _publish_, all you need for this as I understand it is an url to the package repository.

Comment: Thanky @JoakimDanielson, using the `file://...` URL instead of the folder picker did the trick. I do not understand the difference since the folder picker also returns the file URL of the selected folder, doesn't it? I assume this is just another awesome, great and genius design decision by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

@JoakimDanielson pointed me into the correct direction. I don't understand the difference, but Xcode only handles the repository + versioning correctly if the pacage is not added by selecting its folder but by specifying the folders `file://...` URL. Picking a folder using the `Add Local...` button and entering the folders file URL should be same, but obvious it is not.

Anyway, when entering the folders `file://...` URL, everything works as expected and I can select the desired package version. It is **NOT** necessary to create a remote repo (on the local device or some server). The package repo itself is sufficient.

[image]